Wilamowitz-Möllendorf integration to stanza 6 of Sappho Lobel-Page 16 (now stanza 1 of 16b): what does it mean?
The text of the first two lines, as per the papyrus, reads:
]μεν οὐ δύνατον γένεσθαι
] ὂ̣ν ἀνθρώπ[ ]εδέχην δ' ἄρασθαι
The integration in question reads:
[Εὖ μὲν ἴδ]μεν οὐ δύνατον γένεσθαι
[λῷστ'] ὂ̣ν ἀνθρώπ[οις, π]εδέχην δ' ἄρασθαι
[Ἔστι πὰρ θέων μακάρων ἔκοισαν
Τῶν παρεόντων.]
"Well we know that it is impossible for the best things to happen to people, but it is possible (ἔστι πὰρ = πάρεστι) to pray to participate (ἄρασθαι πεδέχην) the ἔκοισαν (??) of the blessed gods (θέων μακάρων), those that are by one's side (Τῶν παρεόντων)" is my attempt at translating this. What is ἔκοισαν? "An appropriate share (implies μοῖραν maybe)"? Or "to partake of the blessed gods[' presence] as much as they are willing to concede, when they are by your side"?

Maybe = ἑκοῦσαν, accusative subject of the infinitive: "to partake willingly/readily"? Also I'd take μακάρων τῶν παρεόντων as depending on πεδέχην, "partake of present blessings".

@TKR that ἔκοισαν is Aeolic for ἑκοῦσαν was never in question, but why is it feminine? Is it referred to Sappho, so "it is possible (for me Sappho) to pray to willingly partake in" whatever? Also, doesn't μακαρ mean blessed, adjective, rather than blessing, noun?

I was thinking of self-reference by Sappho, yes -- not sure how plausible this is but it's the only analysis I can see... Good point about μακάρων (which doesn't seem to be used as a neuter substantive but is common as an epithet of gods) -- so maybe that goes with θέων and only τῶν παρεόντων goes with πεδέχην.

@TKR So "it is possible (for me) to pray the blessed gods to willingly partake in what is present"?

That's the best I can come up with, anyway :)

My conjecture would be future of εκφερω, εξοισομαι with the meaning to win somethng.
